# function from required JS file is not defined

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have this little function:

```
   function nullifyLorem(){
         document.getElementById("loremIpsum").innerHTML ="loremNullified"
   }
```

it is from the file "custom.js" which resides in root/assets/js/lib.
This file is included via

```
     require('./lib/custom');
```

inside the app.js file which resides in root/assets/js.
The import of the custom.js works fine, I get no error about it.

Now I have this button on my landingpage

```
<button class="button" onclick="nullifyLorem()">ClickMe!</button>
```

where I have this inclusion of script at the bottom of my body

`<script src="{{root}}assets/js/app.js"></script>`.

And when I click it, I get this error

Uncaught ReferenceError: nullifyLorem is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Why is this? What am I missing? I read in several posts that this is the way to go when including own JS Files...

Answer (score 1):

The onClick references a function name before it is available and in the wrong context (global / window).
This does not work in general.

Use the unobtrusive way by using and attaching event listeners after your DOM elements are created.